# How to access a file from a client to a server

Tags: c#

```
private void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        {


            string strDir = "http://200.100.0.50/chandu/abc.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(strDir))
            {
                File.Create(strDir);
            }
        }
}
```

I am inserting records in form that will be stored in the server in drive C: but get *URI format was not in the correct format* error.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to use a UNC Path like:

```
\\200.100.0.50\chandu\abc.txt
```

Comment: "http:\\200.100.0.50\chandu\abc.txt" i gave like this again unrecognized escape error is comming

Comment: @user1918410 try `string strDir = @"\\200.100.0.50\chandu\abc.txt"`. You didn't properly escape the backslashes.

Comment: @user1918410, the IO library that determines if a file exists is expecting a local or network path. With the file being on another server you use a simple network UNC path.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebRequest`, then you gain the ability to send an HTTP HEAD request. When you issue the request, you should either get an error (if the file is missing), or a `WebResponse` with a valid `ContentLength` property.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.example.com/"));
request.Method = "HEAD";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", response.ContentLength, response.ContentType);
```

Comment: i am using windows application,above code will work in windows

Answer (score 0):

if the target supports webdav you can either map it as a network drive or just access it directly but you still need to do \200.100.0.5\whatever

Answer (score 0):

Use \ instead of /

On a slightly unrelated note (hopefully I understand your question):

You should create a `WebClient` and use the `DownloadString` function. The function will throw a 404 exception if the file exists.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadString("www.google.com"); // Will work
client.DownloadString("www.asdfawioeufje.com/awefoasdfasdf"); // 404 error
```

As you can see, this is probably a better way of doing what I think you want to do.

Comment: Why does this not work if you're using Windows? I'm confused.